# Unity, C#, Visual studio 2019, folder structure

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I am new to C# and also new to using unity and visual studio, the problem im having right now is that, when i double click my C# script it doesent show the entire folder structure in visual studio 2019. I tried opening the my project through the  Assets -> Open C# Project method but this did not work either. I'm not really sure what to do,[image] if anyone has a method that can work, that will be greatyly appriciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't show the entire folder structure'. Do you mean in the `Solution Explorer`? Also, can you share an image of your entire visual studio application?

Comment: Surely, in the solution explorer, the folder structure is absent.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the Unity world.
If I understand your problem, Unity is only opening one file instead of the whole solution explorer.

I had the same issue after an update from Unity (2019 > 2020).

One of the most common issues for this is your unity preferences.
You have to configure this manually. You can find the option in

edit > Preferences > External Tools > External Script Editor.

Set your external script editor to Visual studio. (https://answers.unity.com/questions/513720/unity-not-opening-solution-in-visual-studio-only-f.html)

This problem could also be caused by a missing package.
You can enable this package in Unity via

Window > Package Manager

and install the Visual Studio Code Editor or Visual Studio Editor (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1632856/visual-studio-2019-wont-open-when-double-clicking.html)

Comment: This solution worked, I had to set the preferences manually to Visuall Studio. Thank you for the help.